# How to check a string is longer than the container div's width in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

E.g:

```
.container{ width:200px; height:16px;overflow:hidden;font-size:13px; }

<div class="container">
I want to know this sentence's width is bigger than my container div's width
</div>
```

and if the string inside the `container` is `much longer` , is there a way I can `animate the string from begin to the end and loop again and again`. But if shorter,just stay!!

**[update]**

`With Don's way`, the `inner element with string's width` aways equal the `width of container` and string was wrapped.So,how can I do to set the `inner element's width` to be the `string's actual length`!?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The inner element has to have this CSS property set: `white-space:nowrap`. That way, its width will be accurate.

Comment: you are right.And I put the text inside a span element and got the length what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should put your string in an inner element (such as `div`, `p`, `h1`, ...) and then compare its width to the container's one.

Answer (score 3):

you could solve that with a ruler:
add to your site that <div>

```
<div id="ruler" style="display: none">
   I want to know this sentence's width is bigger than my container div's width
</div>
```

Now you can get the length of the string and compare it to the length of your .container

```
if ($("#ruler").width() >  $(".container").width()) {
  //what ever you want to do if the string is to long
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a *good* way to figure out if the text exceeds the `div`'s size, although doing some googling does bring us to [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript) and answer.

You could take that and use the jQuery plugin [jQscroller](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqScroller) to scroll the text if it exceeds the div's size.

A simple way if you don't care for the exact width would be to wrap the text in a span element as it will take the size of the text. You can then use `$('span').outerWidth()` and compare it to the `$('#container').width()` if they're the same you can assume the text wrapped around and should be scrolled. If the `span`'s width is smaller it should just stay still. (This method might be inaccurate by a few pixels)